# what is the openai_secret_manager for Whisper?

Tags: openai-whisper

I want to set up Whisper and looked into the documentation.
However, I saw this code when I asked chatgpt for help:

```
model = whisper.load_model("base.en")

# Set up OpenAI credentials
secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secret("openai")
openai.api_key = secrets["api_key"]
```

Could anyone please explain to me if I need this openai_secret_manager? what is it? and why I need it?